# How to prevent the file from public on Digital Ocean Space?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-storage, laravel-filesystem, digital-ocean-spaces

Hi everyone I stuck on Digital Ocean that I want to prevent my file from the public.

**First of all. I set the .env file like this**

```
DO_SPACES_KEY= THE KEY
DO_SPACES_SECRET= THE SECRET
DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT=https://sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com
DO_SPACES_REGION=sgp1
DO_SPACES_BUCKET= MY BUCKET NAME
DO_SPACES_URL=https://mydomain.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com
```

**Then I set the config->filesystem.php**

```
'do_spaces' => [
    'driver' => 's3',
    'key' => env('DO_SPACES_KEY'),
    'secret' => env('DO_SPACES_SECRET'),
    'region' => env('DO_SPACES_REGION'),
    'bucket' => env('DO_SPACES_BUCKET'),
    'url' => env('DO_SPACES_URL'),
    'endpoint' => env('DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT'),
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

**After that make the controller store the file**

```
    //convert image name
    $stringImageReFormat=base64_encode('_'.time());
    $ext=$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $imageName=$stringImageReFormat.".".$ext;
    $imageEncoded=File::get($request->image);

    //upload & insert
     Storage::disk('do_spaces')->put('public/user_image/'.$imageName,$imageEncoded);

    // Insert Data to Table
    $user=new User();
    $user->image=$imageName;
    $user->save();
```

**On my blade template, I retrieve the file like this**

```
{{ Storage::disk('do_spaces')->url('public/user_image/'.$user->image) }}
```

**This is what I get when I don't set the visibility to public**

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<BucketName>mybucket</BucketName>
<RequestId>tx0000000000000088d0617-00607228ae-13200e4-sgp1b</RequestId>
<HostId>13200e4-sgp1b-sgp1-zg02</HostId>
</Error>
```

If I set the visibility in the filesystem.php to public. I can see the files without authentication.

Thank you in advance for any help or advice.